# error in installing hiredis through npm

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-12.04, npm, hiredis

I am trying to install hiredis through npm and it is giving error as

```
  npm  install hiredis redis

  npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/redis
  npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/hiredis
  npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/hiredis
  npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/redis
  npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bindings
  npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bindings

  > hiredis@0.1.16 install /home/mohit/node_modules/hiredis
  > node-gyp rebuild

  make: Entering directory `/home/mohit/node_modules/hiredis/build'
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/hiredis/deps/hiredis/hiredis.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/hiredis/deps/hiredis/net.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/hiredis/deps/hiredis/sds.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/hiredis/deps/hiredis/async.o
  AR(target) Release/obj.target/deps/hiredis.a
  COPY Release/hiredis.a
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/hiredis/src/hiredis.o
  make: g++: Command not found
  make: *** [Release/obj.target/hiredis/src/hiredis.o] Error 127
  make: Leaving directory `/home/mohit/node_modules/hiredis/build'
  gyp ERR! build error 
  gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
  gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit     
  (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:267:23)
  gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
  gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:807:12)
  gyp ERR! System Linux 3.2.0-23-generic
  gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-        
  gyp.js" "rebuild"
  gyp ERR! cwd /home/mohit/node_modules/hiredis
  gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.28
  gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.13.0
  gyp ERR! not ok 
  npm ERR! hiredis@0.1.16 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
  npm ERR! Exit status 1
  npm ERR! 
  npm ERR! Failed at the hiredis@0.1.16 install script.
  npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the hiredis package,
  npm ERR! not with npm itself.
  npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
  npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
  npm ERR! You can get their info via:
  npm ERR!     npm owner ls hiredis
  npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

  npm ERR! System Linux 3.2.0-23-generic
  npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "hiredis" "redis"
  npm ERR! cwd /home/mohit
  npm ERR! node -v v0.10.28
  npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.9
  npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
  npm ERR! 
  npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
  npm ERR!     /home/mohit/npm-debug.log
  npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

this may be a possible duplicate of

[Hiredis installing error using NPM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18092489/hiredis-installing-error-using-npm)

but that question been not answered and is not clear

Comment: I am failing on zlib.. "Error: incorrect header check at zlib._binding.onerror (zlib.js:295:17)"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error seems to be finding c/c++ compiler problem.

```
make: g++: Command not found
```

It could be g++ is not installed or not in the path where make command can find.

Do "which g++" from the prompt and see where it is.

Comment: What was the error/output? I ran mine on the mac, I got: /usr/bin/g++

Comment: i got it ,it seems that g++ was not installed ,i installed it using    sudo apt-get install g++ and then again run   npm  install hiredis redis and it worked ,thanks